# VSCode Syntax Highlighting for Javascript doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

i got a little problem over here and i don't get why. My Syntax Highlighting doesn't work on a normal .js file whilst i've Babel Javascript & the Atom One Pro Theme activated as extensions. Don't get whats going wrong here.

[picture of the code how it looks right now](https://i.gyazo.com/c3a1eee7dc45673023cf8d4a6f5e34c6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the **Template Literals** plugin from the visual studio marketplace.  Refer to the below blog for the exact reason.

Reference:

https://medium.com/@julienetienne/javascript-the-need-for-template-literal-highlighting-ff5806adc814

Comment: Sadly it didn't work out for me. Added it to my extensions & activated it but it still doesn't highlight the html & js inside the template literal